# Javascript click function exceptions

Tags: javascript, click

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function()
```

I do not need to do it, if `href = #first, #second, #third`. I know that  it must be  like `:not([href=#first])`.

But how to write for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('a').not('[href="#first"],[href="#second"],[href="#third"]').click(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is to add a class "clickable" for clickable element or "notClickable" for specific elements. It will be much easier for manage your code.